# How to set Xmx and Xms properly in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jvm, java-11

I'm trying to fix the heap size memory using -Xmx50M in build.gradle file, it doesn't work, the memory size always goes beyond 50M.

***Details :***

**My build.gradle**

```
   plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.10'
}

group 'com.karrty'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.7.1'
}

sourceCompatibility = '17'
targetCompatibility = '17'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'com.karrty.karrtyversion1'
    mainClass  = 'com.karrty.karrtyversion1.Principle.main'
}

javafx {
    version = '16'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.0')
}

run {

    jvmArgs = [
         
            "-Xms50m",
            "-Xmx50m"
    ]
}
```

**Screen shot of the issue**

[image]

as you can see, the app has located 500MB in memory and using almost 250MB of it, even tho I specified the heap memory size to be 50MB .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason using the short VM arguments `Xms50m` and `Xmx50m` is not working with gradle, but the full expressions `-XX:MaxHeapSize=50m` and `-XX:InitialHeapSize=50` are working, if you also have the same issue , just replace those short expressions with their full expressions and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Am not 100% sure , but i think you should be using gradle.properties to set `-Xmx50M` .
You can check [the official docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties) to make sure .
gradle.properties should look like this

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m "-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"
```

This is the default and you can change based on what you need to do .

Comment: unfortunatly thats not working either, i think inserting VM arguments in gradle.properties or in build.gradle (as i did) is the same, the only difference is the notation